# server side render with react router with data fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm in the process of upgrading to version 1 of React Router and can't get the data fetching side of my code to work on the server, i.e. initial server-side render.

What I am trying to do is fetch data from the server depending on the selected route. Each component has a *static fetchData method* and along with a global data method I build up the data to then pass into the controller view component defined in the route config.

My code is below:

```
match({routes, location: req.url}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {

  fetchData(renderProps).then((data) => {
      //page specific data
      return data;
    }).then((data) => {
      //global data
      getGlobalData().then((appData) => {

        data.app = appData;

        data = Immutable.fromJS(data);

        let templateLocals = {
          "data": data
        };    console.log('trying to render');
      templateLocals.content = renderToString(
    <RoutingContext {...renderProps} data={data}/>
  );
  res.send(layout(templateLocals));
    });

  });
});
```

What I would like to do as before with `<Handler> pre V1.0` is pass my data as props into the app (I can see that the data is correct and there as I pass it into the RoutingContext component). But what I see from RoutingContext module is that the implementation will not allow this. It only picks up *history,location,params,route,routeParams,routes* and not any *custom props*.

The example of server side render does not go this far, but am keen to understand how I should handle such an example as I upgrade?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Redux by any chance? This isn't trivial to figure out but if you're using Redux I can perhaps give you a hand. Been there, done that, with much frustration along the way I may add.

Comment: no, simply react and react-router. I had this implementation working fine before I upgraded to V1. Seems like a fairly common use case to me - but can't find any examples!

Comment: +1 the documentation is really lacking on this point -- it's a super common use case and something that worked before the upgrade no sweat -- I managed to get it working like I said but with Redux in the mix so it won't be exactly the same as for you -- even then though there is [this bug](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2714) which is super annoying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the async-props repo, which provides both an example as well as utilities for handling this sort of data fetching isomorphically: https://github.com/rackt/async-props.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Redux, take a look also to https://github.com/Rezonans/redux-async-connect
It's similar to AsyncProps, but better fits for projects that uses Redux